# Informatica Error during SQL server table load

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica and I am getting the below error while running a simple DB to DB table load using Informatica.

```
Message Code: WRT_8229
Message: Database errors occurred: 
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '$'.
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
FnName: Execute -- [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error
```

I am not using any parameter in the mapping and I do not understand why I am getting that:

> 'Incorrect syntax near '$'' error.

I have another mapping that loads the same table, but that is working without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when the target table contains a column name with a space or special character. For your case it seems its `$`. Now, you need to add `QuotedId=Yes` to your odbc.ini file for target connection entry. Check if you are using same connection as the mapping that works. If not, you need to append below parameter to your connection.

1. open .odbc.ini. This exists in $ODBC_INI location.
2. append below entry and save it.

```
[TGT_CONN]
...
QuotedId=Yes
```

Explanation - QuotedID parameter determines whether the driver uses quoted identifiers while writing/reading. So Infa should use sql like `SELECT "abc_$" from "table"`